# rewriteRules WP6

Tags: rewrite-rules

I’ve got a custom post type `slides` which is set up this way

```
function register_slides() {

    $labels_slides = array(
        'name' => __( 'Slides', 'slides' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Slide', 'slides' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Slides', 'slides' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New', 'slides' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Slide', 'slides' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Slide', 'slides' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Slide', 'slides' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Slides', 'slides' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No Slides found', 'slides' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Slides found in Trash', 'slides' ),
    );

    $args_slides = array(
        'labels' => $labels_slides,
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-products',
        'supports' => array(
            'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'revisions', 'page-attributes',
        ),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => sprintf( '%s/&slides_categories&', __( 'products', 'slides' ) ),
            'with_front' => false,
        ),
    );

    register_post_type( 'slide', $args_slides );

    $labels_slides_categories = array(
        'name' => __( 'Slide Categories', 'slides' ),
    );

    $args_slides_categories = array(
        'labels' => $labels_slides_categories,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => __( 'products', 'slides' ),
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true,
        ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'slides_categories', 'slide', $args_slides_categories );
```

and following *rewriteRules* function, which worked fines in WP5 but in WP6 not work anymore. I already debugged but WP is not running through.

```
function slide_rewrite_rule( $rules ) {
    $newRule1 = sprintf( '%s/([^/]+)/(?:(?!\bpage\b).)+/([^/]+)/?$', __( 'products', 'slides' ) ); // matches products (slides) but let WordPress do taxonomy pagination stuff correctly
    $newRule2 = sprintf( '%s/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(?:(?!\bpage\b).)+/([^/]+)/?$', __( 'products', 'slides' ) );
    $newRules  = array();
    $newRules[$newRule1] = 'index.php?slide=$matches[2]';
    $newRules[$newRule2] = 'index.php?slide=$matches[3]';
    $rules->rules = $newRules + $rules->rules;
}
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'slide_rewrite_rule' );
```

also tried this `add_filter('rewrite_rules_array',……………)`

The Slug is made of multilevel categories for example

> https://example.com/products/cat1/subcat2/prodsname/

I would like to end up with the slug

> https://example.com/products/cat1/subcat2/prodsname/

on my CPT detail page and that is currently no longer possible, but it worked wonderfully in WP5 with the `slide_rewrite_rule()` function. The CPT registration is correct and the permalink placeholder is correct in the *wp-admin*: `https://example.com/products/&prods_categories&/prodsname/` because the product should not only be reached in one category, even in all categories . The detail page should be reached in all selected categories correctly, for example even this `https://example.com/products/cat2/subcat3/prodsname/`

Comment: You need to return something in a filter. So try `return $rules;` after you've added yours in

Comment: thanks, i already checked and it works.